# Biblatex does not print year in the references with apa setting

Tags: biblatex, overleaf, apa7

I am unable to get APA7 style citation to work properly on Overleaf.

The reference guidelines suggest that the bibliography should look like this:

[image: Bibliography format suggestions for APA7]

However, in my case, the reference item in the bibliography does not print the year. Can someone please help?

Below is a minimum working example. My main working document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=apa, 
backend=biber, url = false, doi = false]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{literature.bib}


\begin{document}

\section{Introduction and Literature Review}\label{sect:introduction}

For example, \autocite{dietvorst2018overcoming} shows that firms can reduce algorithm aversion by giving humans some control to revise an algorithm's recommendation. In another example, \textcite{sun2022predicting} illustrate an approach to improve human adherence to the algorithmic recommendation by modifying the initial algorithm to include the predictors of human deviations from its recommendations. 

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

literature.bib file

```
@article{dietvorst2018overcoming,
  doi = {10.1287/mnsc.2016.2643},
  url = {https://doi.org/10.1287/mnsc.2016.2643},
  year = {2018},
  month = mar,
  publisher = {Institute for Operations Research and the Management Sciences ({INFORMS})},
  volume = {64},
  number = {3},
  pages = {1155--1170},
  author = {Berkeley J. Dietvorst and Joseph P. Simmons and Cade Massey},
  title = {Overcoming Algorithm Aversion: People Will Use Imperfect Algorithms If They Can (Even Slightly) Modify Them},
  journal = {Management Science}
}

@article{sun2022predicting,
  doi = {10.1287/mnsc.2021.3990},
  url = {https://doi.org/10.1287/mnsc.2021.3990},
  year = {2022},
  month = feb,
  publisher = {Institute for Operations Research and the Management Sciences ({INFORMS})},
  volume = {68},
  number = {2},
  pages = {846--865},
  author = {Jiankun Sun and Dennis J. Zhang and Haoyuan Hu and Jan A. Van Mieghem},
  title = {Predicting Human Discretion to Adjust Algorithmic Prescription: A Large-Scale Field Experiment in Warehouse Operations},
  journal = {Management Science}
}
```

This is the output I am currently seeing:

[image: Screenshot of faulty output]

Files list generated by adding \listfiles to my preamble:

```
*File List*
 article.cls    2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
biblatex.sty    2020/12/31 v3.16 programmable bibliographies (PK/MW)
pdftexcmds.sty    2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
   iftex.sty    2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
 ltxcmds.sty    2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
etoolbox.sty    2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
kvoptions.sty    2020-10-07 v3.14 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
  logreq.sty    2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
  logreq.def    2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
  ifthen.sty    2020/11/24 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  blx-dm.def    2020/12/31 v3.16 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
     apa.dbx    2020/08/28 v9.14 APA biblatex style data model
blx-unicode.def
blx-compat.def    2020/12/31 v3.16 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
biblatex.def    2020/12/31 v3.16 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
standard.bbx    2020/12/31 v3.16 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
     apa.bbx    2020/08/28 v9.14 APA biblatex references style
     apa.cbx    2020/08/28 v9.14 APA biblatex citation style
biblatex.cfg    
l3backend-xetex.def    2021-07-12 L3 backend support: XeTeX
  ts1cmr.fd    2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
 english.lbx    2020/12/31 v3.16 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
american.lbx    2020/12/31 v3.16 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
american-apa.lbx    2020/08/28 v9.14 APA biblatex localisation
english-apa.lbx    2020/08/28 v9.14 APA biblatex localisation
   expl3.sty    2021-07-12 L3 programming layer (loader) 
blx-case-expl3.sty    2020/12/31 v3.16 expl3 case changing code for biblatex
  xparse.sty    2021-06-18 L3 Experimental document command parser
  output.bbl
```

Files list generated after changing the TeX Live Version to 2023 on Overleaf:

```
*File List*
 article.cls    2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
biblatex.sty    2023/03/05 v3.19 programmable bibliographies (PK/MW)
pdftexcmds.sty    2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
   iftex.sty    2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
 ltxcmds.sty    2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
etoolbox.sty    2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
  keyval.sty    2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
kvoptions.sty    2022-06-15 v3.15 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2022-10-05 v1.19 Key value parser (HO)
  logreq.sty    2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
  logreq.def    2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
  ifthen.sty    2022/04/13 v1.1d Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  blx-dm.def    2023/03/05 v3.19 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
     apa.dbx    2023/03/20 v9.17 APA biblatex style data model
blx-unicode.def
blx-compat.def    2023/03/05 v3.19 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
biblatex.def    2023/03/05 v3.19 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
standard.bbx    2023/03/05 v3.19 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
     apa.bbx    2023/03/20 v9.17 APA biblatex references style
     apa.cbx    2023/03/20 v9.17 APA biblatex citation style
biblatex.cfg    
   expl3.sty    2023-06-30 L3 programming layer (loader) 
l3backend-xetex.def    2023-04-19 L3 backend support: XeTeX
blx-case-expl3.sty    2023/03/05 v3.19 expl3 case changing code for biblatex
  xparse.sty    2023-02-02 L3 Experimental document command parser
  ts1cmr.fd    2023/04/13 v2.5m Standard LaTeX font definitions
 english.lbx    2023/03/05 v3.19 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
american.lbx    2023/03/05 v3.19 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
american-apa.lbx    2023/03/20 v9.17 APA biblatex localisation
english-apa.lbx    2023/03/20 v9.17 APA biblatex localisation
  output.bbl
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se, and thanks for including a minimal document and `.bib` file with your question. Your sample document however produces the year correctly in my test. Can you verify that you are running an up-to-date version of `biblatex-apa`? Add `\listfiles` to your preamble and then report back what version is returned.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I am doing this on Overleaf, so perhaps that is causing the issue?

Is this what you asked me to generate? 


Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex style data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'apa.dbx' found.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-apa/apa.dbx
File: apa.dbx 2020/08/28 v9.14 APA biblatex style data model
)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. In Overleaf you can choose the version of TeX Live that compiles your project. Click on the Menu button at the top left, and then choose the 2023 version of TeX Live to compile your project. By default Overleaf won't change versions, so if you started this document some time ago, that's probably why you still are using the 2021 version.

Comment: Interesting! I changed the TeX version to 2023, but no luck, unfortunately. However, I see these three warnings and I wonder if that is relevant? 

Package biblatex Warning: Macro 'date+extradate' undefined.
(biblatex)                Using \newbibmacro.


Package biblatex Warning: Macro 'volume+number+eid' already defined.
(biblatex)                Using \renewbibmacro.


Package biblatex Warning: Macro 'apaeditorstrg' already defined.
(biblatex)                Using \renewbibmacro.

Comment: Can you show the `\listfiles` output with the updated system? It looks like only part of the packages was updated (or more likely you have an outdated version of some package hanging around locally).

Comment: I just edited the main question to append the ```\listfiles``` after changing the TeX Live version to 2023. Thanks so much for trying to help!

Comment: That is not files from TeXLive 2023. I have up to day TL23 installed and both `article.cls` and `biblatex.sty` are from 2023. Do you have two latex installation? Which OS are you on?

Comment: Your example seems to work fine with texlive2023 from overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/read/jvhgwhvwbdcf Can you double check in your overleaf side bar that you are really using TL23?

Comment: The TeX Live 2023 package versions look good on first glance. Can you clear the cache/recompile from scratch (https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache) and recompile? As samcarter demonstrates the output should be different and I get the expected (correct) output (with years) both locally and on Overleaf (if tested with TL2023).

Comment: Curiously, I did not manage to reproduce your wrong output with any of the Overleaf TeX Lives I tried (I tested 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022 and 2023): The year was always present. Are you absolutely sure that the files on your problematic Overleaf project are exactly as shown here?

Comment: Any news here? As explained in the comments we failed to reproduce the error you are asking about. It would be great if you could verify (ideally in a new Overleaf project) that the information you have posted so far is indeed sufficient to reproduce the issue. Otherwise the chances that we are able to help are slim and the question will probably have to be closed as lacking detail to reproduce.

Comment: Sorry for not following up. Got caught up in trying to meet the deadline for which I needed this formatting. In a brand new Overleaf project, I have been unable to reproduce the issue. The year prints well according to the AP guidelines. 
Even though the minimal example I shared here is based on the ```article``` class, I need to format based on a personalized class file. Even with my personalized class file, I am unable to reproduce the issue in a brand new Overleaf project. Within the same Overleaf project the issue persists regardless of the class file I choose.

Comment: Does the problem persist if you work in a copy of your project? Did you clear the cache as suggested in one of my earlier comments? If you cannot reproduce the problem reliably outside one specific Overleaf project, we cannot really help, since there is nothing we have to start from, but you may want to get in touch with Overleaf staff. They are usually very eager to help.

Comment: I have not tried to work in a copy of my project. I did clear the cache as suggested -- unfortunately, that did not help. As I am unable to reproduce the problem reliably outside a specific Overleaf project, I understand that this question may not be very useful to the community. Please close the question. Thanks to all of you for trying to help!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem cannot be replicated with the information provided so far and does not appear in other Overleaf projects (as also demonstrated above). Since the issue cannot be reproduced, it cannot be investigated any further.